# Trigger "tick box" message in checkbox field

Tags: reactjs

I am using React, and I would like to find a way to trigger this message (that now triggers only when pressing the `type="submit"` button, on will, is there any action I can use to trigger this message at any point (for example if a user presses any other button)

[image]

```
              <input
                id="conditions"
                type="checkbox"
                name="conditions"
                ref={acceptConditions}
                required
              ></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here are a few approaches, that works.

**approach 1**
Using the `reportValidity()`

This function will check the validity of the element and then trigger the event.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const acceptConditions = useRef();
  const formRef = useRef();
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    acceptConditions.current.reportValidity();
  };
  return (
    <form ref={formRef}>
      <input
        id="conditions"
        type="checkbox"
        name="conditions"
        ref={acceptConditions}
        required
      ></input>
      <span>Tick this box to continue</span>
      <br />
      <button type={"submit"}>submit the form</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Imposter button</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This is a good apporach And one that i recommend.

**approach 2:**

First of all if you want any other button to trigger the same event then you can do is make a reference to the `form` and then `submit` the `form` manually on the button press.

Here is an example.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const acceptConditions = useRef();
  const formRef = useRef();
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(formRef.current.submit);
  };
  return (
    <form ref={formRef}>
      <input
        id="conditions"
        type="checkbox"
        name="conditions"
        ref={acceptConditions}
        required
      ></input>
      <span>Tick this box to continue</span>
      <br />
      <button type={"submit"}>submit the form</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Imposter button</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

in the above code the `imposter button` will trigger the same action as the button with the `type="submit"`.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with `reportValidity()` [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity)

```js
setTimeout(() =>
  document.getElementById('example').reportValidity(), 
  3000
)
```

```html
<input id="example" type="checkbox" required />
```